# nhibernate HbmMapping to Xml

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I am using NHibernate mapping-by-code to map the classes.

Sometimes, in order to debug my NHibernate configuration, I would require to check exactly what were the settings passed over to NHibernate, and it is quite difficult do debug the mapping-by-code.

Is there any way where you could convert the generated HbmMapping, back into the Xml file, just as if typed by hand?

This would help a lot in diagnosing if the problem is lying from my mappings!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Option 1**

Be warned this will write the XML into your BIN folder causing the IIS pool to recycle, so run once and then comment the `WriteAllXmlMapping` line back out!

```
var mapper = new ModelMapper();
mapper.AddMappings(typeof(CmsMeta).Assembly.GetTypes());

//This will write all the XML into the bin/mappings folder
mapper.CompileMappingForEachExplicitlyAddedEntity().WriteAllXmlMapping();
```

**Option 2**

This will give you a a single large XML file that you can add a breakpoint to.

```
var mapper = new ModelMapper();
mapper.AddMappings(typeof(CmsMeta).Assembly.GetTypes());
var mapping = mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();

//you could add a breakpoint here! 
var mappingXml = mapping.AsString();
```

The source is from a [blog post](http://puredotnetcoder.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/view-xml-generated-when-mapping-by-code.html) I wrote a while ago.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I am using NH3.3, and found out that 'CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities' is an extension method found in `NHibernate.Mappings.ByCode` working on an `IEnumerable<HbmMapping>`.  It is not found directly in the `ModelMapper`, as listed above.

Unfortunately, there is a 'Serialize' method in the same `MappingsExtensions` file in the NH source code that is not public.  I've copied the code into my general code base, so that I don't have to touch the NH code base.  I will repost my solution below due to length.

Comment: Sorry my fault - didn't notice the last one was `AsString` and not `ToString`!  That work's brilliantly, and really thanks for your very fast reply!

Comment: Just have to finally say, how many times I was here to copy paste that. Blody fantastic answer ;)